# How to append extra fields to list in JOLT?

Tags: json, jolt

I'm trying to add some extra fields to the list which are not there in the input json. I can add fields if it's an object, but I'm not able to add the fields to an array. Please, someone help me write a specification.

input JSON is:

```json
[
  {
    "List": [
      {
        "ITEM_NO": "abcd"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

written a spec file

Spec File is:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "List": {
          "0": {
            "ITEM_NO": "risk[0].one"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "risk": [
        {
          "two": "efgh",
          "three": "ijkl"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

But output is not like expected

expected output is:

```json
{
  "risk": [
    {
      "one": "abcd",
      "two": "efgh",
      "three": "ijkl"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to add extra fields?

Comment: Hi there, I'm looking for answer to this question. please help me out. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "List": {
          "0": {
            "ITEM_NO": "risk[0].one"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "risk[]": {
        "0": {
          "two": "efgh",
          "three": "ijkl"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Produces the output you want, but not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can figure it out by using a single shift transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "List": {
          "*": {
            "*": "r[&1].one",
            "#efgh": "r[&1].two",
            "#ijkl": "r[&1].three"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where you can hard code desired strings to be placed as a value in the output through use of **`"#"`** wildcard, and **`"*"`** to represent all attributes(in this case the only attribute is the one with key name **`"one"`**).

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]